# Why does the date value display differently between "Cell" and "Fomula Text" in Excel?

Tags: excel

Take a date "12/31/2016 00:00" for example. If we input this date into Excel, we will see that the displayed one in the Formula Text is "12/31/2016  12:00:00 AM" (Fig1). It seems that the two dates are different of 12 hours. Why does it happen?

[image: Fig1]

Comment: Those aren't different by 12 hours, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Excel stores the datetime as a number behind the scenes. Currently it is `43430.33` where I live. What you see in the cell is merely a formatted version of that. What shows up in the formula bar is a different format of that same datetime. They are 100% the same though, and underneath, they are merely a number. `43430.33`

Comment: They're exactly the same time. But why one is "00:00", the other is "12:00 AM"? I mean, if we don't "check" them by "number behind the scenes", we may mistake that one is midnight, the other is midday. Hope for your help.